# Is it possible to make a BLE HID without a microcontroller like an Arduino?

Tags: converter, bluetooth-low-energy, hid, hc-05, hm-10

I am in a vocational highschool. I have a project where I have to make a HID like a keyboard or a mouse (wired) into Bluetooth wireless.

I've read many articles before like using an Arduino Pro Mini 3.3V with an HC-05 or 06 as Bluetooth module and USB RS232 to flash the Bluetooth module program.

Source:
https://github.com/juancgarcia/HID-Relay

My question:

1. Is it possible to just flash the Bluetooth module and connect it into the keyboard PCB to make it happen?
2. Is there any like 2 in 1 BLE and microcontroller all together as one part?
   If there any, is it more recommended than buying an Arduino and Bluetooth module separately? How to make it?
3. I've also found that the newest model of HC-05 is the HM-10 or 11.  Can I just swap it and do the same like instructed in source just to replace the old HT-05/06 to the newer version?
4. Regarding master or slave type of Bluetooth module, for HID to BLE, which one will do the job?

I also found this source which makes me confused which one I should try because I have a limited budget. I live in south east asia so it is kind of hard to get BLE modules and stuff.

Here another source:
https://geekhack.org/index.php?topic=62236.0#top

I'm trying to make itlike that one ( the second source link ) but didn't understand it fully.

Is there anyone who has tried to make HID to BLE before? Can you share how to do it?

Comment: this may help ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=2+in+1+BLE+and+microcontroller&ia=web

Comment: Tedra, please help me understand better. It sounds as though you are tasked with taking an existing keyboard or mouse, likely hard-wired into USB and depending upon desktop operating system HID drivers for their communication ***and then*** creating something that will *host* the USB and *act-like* HID over USB to the keyboard so that it thinks it's talking with a host USB port and standard HID driver, and then provide BLE on the other end. Is that it? (Not so easy.) Or am I totally off-base?

Answer (score 1):

1 - HC-05 / HC-06 are not standalone modules it won't work (there are configured with the famous AT commands, someone needs to send those)

2 - I was using an Arduino Nano coupled with a Adafruit Bluefruit LE SPI Friend [Product webpage](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2633) now I only use an ESP32 with the library [ESP 32 BLE Keyboard](https://github.com/T-vK/ESP32-BLE-Keyboard)

3 - I don't know, I will look into it

4 - BLE HID is always a slave

I think you misunderstood something the HC-05 is not "programmed" it is configured, I guess what you mean is that HID is not native in the module so they replace the firmware to add the HID functionality.

Comment: Mat , how you configure the esp32 , or connect it to keyboard? Like example the what pin to connect to the d+ and d- something like that...

Comment: Now I'm a bit lost you want to convert a usb keyboard to a wireless one or you want to create a keyboard ?
I guess for the conversion you should buy an existing module, anyway if you need to work on USB protocol you will need to program the usb stack protocol to decode the signals

Comment: Convert keyboard to wireless , tbh such as module didn't exist in my country That's why i went here , if it does exist need to buy it from outside my country like china or usa . But won't have enough time. I also already order the esp32 still on it's way to my place

Comment: Looking very quickly https://hackaday.com/2016/09/04/convert-any-usb-keyboard-to-bluetooth/ there are some on aliexpress etc